# Write a dictionary to Excel using ClosedXML library

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have a dictionary, the key is a string, the value is a list of string. I want to write it into Excel using the [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) library.

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<string>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
List<string> list3 = new List<string>();
List<string> list4 = new List<string>();

list1.Add("a1","b1","c1");
list2.Add("a2","b2","c2");
list3.Add("a3","b3","c3");
list4.Add("a4","b4","c4");

data.Add("head1", list1);
data.Add("head2", list2);
data.Add("head3", list3);
data.Add("head4", list4);
```

So you see the keys are "head1","head2","head3","head4".
The expected result in the excel cells should like

```
head1   head2 head3 head4
a1      a2    a3    a4
b1      b2    b3    b4
c1      c2    c3    c4
```

If I follow [this link closedXml](https://closedxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introToStyling.html), `ws.Cell(1,1).Value = "Hello World!";` is not working at all.  It seems the Cell's arguments only accept bool value rather than int. I mean that the example in the link maybe wrong.

Is there a better way to finish the task in C#?

Comment: Can you show us the block of code you utilized using `ClosedXML` to add the data to the sheet? The context clues may help.

Comment: Yes, please show the code that isn't working.

Comment: Also, you can't add multiple items to a list with a single call to `Add()` like that, but you can do: `List<string> list1 = new List<string> {"a1", "b1", "c1"};`

Comment: In fact, you can initialize the dictionary in one line instead of 13: `var data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> { { "head1", new List<string> { "a1", "b1", "c1" } }, { "head2", new List<string> { "a2", "b2", "c2" } }, { "head3", new List<string> { "a3", "b3", "c3" } }, { "head4", new List<string> { "a4", "b4", "c4" } }, };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the link and used this code to write columns and rows to spreadsheet,

1. You can assign string values to the cell.
2. Use two different loop counters, `row` and `col` to go about the spreadsheet to fill in the dictionary.
3. Row and Col counters starts with 1
4. Row counter needs to reset after each column is filled in.

```
using ClosedXML.Excel; // ClosedXML used for this solution...
```

```
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
    {
        { "head1", new List<string>() { "a1", "b1", "c1" } },
        { "head2", new List<string>() { "a2", "b2", "c2" } },
        { "head3", new List<string>() { "a3", "b3", "c3" } },
        { "head4", new List<string>() { "a4", "b4", "c4" } },
    };

    IXLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
    IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");

    int col = 1;
    foreach (var key in data.Keys)
    {
        int row = 1; // Starts with 1
        ws.Cell(row++, col).Value = key;

        foreach (var val in data[key])
            ws.Cell(row++, col).Value = val;

        col++;
    }

    wb.SaveAs(@"C:\temp\excel.xlsx");
```

**Output In Excel**

```
    head1   head2 head3 head4
    a1      a2    a3    a4
    b1      b2    b3    b4
    c1      c2    c3    c4
```